# Adding SQL Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlparameter

What is the difference between:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("search", "% " + myValue + " %");
```

and:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "% " + myValue + " %");
```

The difference above is with and without the @ symbol. Does it do anything special?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the variant with the '@'. The '@' symbol signifies a variable or a stored procedure / function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

in sql stored procs or functions you must specify parameters name by '@' sign at the beginning of their name